# Is there a way to estimate the transaction size?

Tags: transactions, account, signature, transaction, serialization

Currently to get the size of a transaction I have to do the following

```
const tx = new Transaction().add(...)
const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
const signed = await wallet.signTransaction(tx);
signed.partialSign(...); // add if needed
console.log('tx len', signed.serialize().length);
```

My question: is there a way to estimate the tx size before signing and getting the blockhash?

By looking at the [cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#issues-with-legacy-transactions), I think a starting point is: `32 * # accounts + 64 * # signatures`, however, I'm still missing some bytes which I think are due to metadata? How can I get the size of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many thanks to @Jordan! After digging a bit more I think I got to a decent solution.

Here is the breakdown. For each tx we have:

- a compact array of signatures, `64 bytes` each
- a header array with: # signatures, # read-only accounts that need signatures, # read-only accounts that don't need signatures, `3 bytes` total
- a compact array of accounts, `32 bytes` each
- a blockhash, `32 bytes`
- a compact array of instructions.

Each instruction has this format:

- index of program id, `1 byte`
- compact array of account indexes, `1 byte` for each index
- compact array of opaque bytes, `1 byte` each

Moreover, whenever there is a compact array, we need to add `1-3 bytes` depending on how many elements are there in the array, more info [here](https://beta.docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#compact-u16-format).

This is the code, I tested it against several txs and seems to work well (legacy transactions only):

```
import { PublicKey, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';

/**
 * @param tx a solana transaction
 * @param feePayer the publicKey of the signer
 * @returns size in bytes of the transaction
 */
const getTxSize = (tx: Transaction, feePayer: PublicKey): number => {
    const feePayerPk = [feePayer.toBase58()];

    const signers = new Set<string>(feePayerPk);
    const accounts = new Set<string>(feePayerPk);

    const ixsSize = tx.instructions.reduce((acc, ix) => {
        ix.keys.forEach(({ pubkey, isSigner }) => {
            const pk = pubkey.toBase58();
            if (isSigner) signers.add(pk);
            accounts.add(pk);
        });

        accounts.add(ix.programId.toBase58());

        const nIndexes = ix.keys.length;
        const opaqueData = ix.data.length;

        return (
            acc +
            1 + // PID index
            compactArraySize(nIndexes, 1) +
            compactArraySize(opaqueData, 1)
        );
    }, 0);

    return (
        compactArraySize(signers.size, 64) + // signatures
        3 + // header
        compactArraySize(accounts.size, 32) + // accounts
        32 + // blockhash
        compactHeader(tx.instructions.length) + // instructions
        ixsSize
    );
};

// COMPACT ARRAY

const LOW_VALUE = 127; // 0x7f
const HIGH_VALUE = 16383; // 0x3fff

/**
 * Compact u16 array header size
 * @param n elements in the compact array
 * @returns size in bytes of array header
 */
const compactHeader = (n: number) => (n <= LOW_VALUE ? 1 : n <= HIGH_VALUE ? 2 : 3);

/**
 * Compact u16 array size
 * @param n elements in the compact array
 * @param size bytes per each element
 * @returns size in bytes of array
 */
const compactArraySize = (n: number, size: number) => compactHeader(n) + n * size;
```

Answer (score 5):

The blockhash is always the same length (32 bytes) and the signature(s) are always the same length (64 bytes each).

You should be able set the `feePayer` to `new PublicKey(0)` and set the `recentBlockhash` to `new PublicKey(0).toBase58()` (or `"11111111111111111111111111111111"`), then serialize it without signing:

```
const serialized = transaction.serialize({
  verifySignatures: false,
  requireAllSignatures: false,
})
```

Adding a byte for the number of signatures, I *think* you should be able to get the total size with:

```
const size = serialized.length + 1 + (transaction.signatures.length * 64);
```

The extra 1 byte is to store the number of signatures. https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/transactions#transaction-format has the details.

You should test this against a valid, complete transaction to see if it's off. If it is, it should be by some predictable factor.